# Links on some pages are displayed as subscripts on Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, election, mobile-chrome

Links on some pages are displayed as subscripts on Chrome for Android. Example from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/6:

[image]

Environment:

- Android 12; Pixel 6 Build/SQ1D.220105.007
- Chrome 114.0.5735.147

Comment: No repro on Chrome Android (Chrome 114.0.5735.130). Maybe, provide some more links?

Comment: @RandomPerson-onstrike sorry that's the only link where I saw that

Comment: Your post says "Links on some pages". Perhaps, change it to one ;)

Comment: @RandomPerson-onstrike I'd guess this affects all such election pages with quoted links